# why my PHP function is showing me blank page

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am trying to upload a file in my uploads folder but whenever when I click submit it
shows me blank page nothing happens.
This is the code below of PHP

```
<?php
$file_name=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
$targetdir='uploads/';
$target_file=$targetdir.basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$file_tmp=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
$file_type=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];
$uploadok=1;
$name=$_POST['yourname'];
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
     if($file_type=="application/pdf"){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
         echo "file uplaoded";
}
elseif($check!==false) {
       move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
        echo "file is an image";
        echo "File will be show by your name".$name;
        $uploadok=1;
     }
else{
    echo "file type is wrong";
}
}


?>
```

and this is my ajax code

```
function take() {
            xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=callback:
            xmlhttp.open("GET","uploads.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        function callback() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById('display').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        }
```

Comment: [How to Debug in PHP](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php)

Comment: What do you see for `$_POST['submit']` when you dump out $_POST? `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: you're are uploading a file using a GET request. perhaps that's the problem.

Comment: I changed it to Post but still showing blank page .

Comment: I am using xampp server ,when I tried this code on 000webhost site, it was running but when I treid this code on another hosting blank page comes out, means the code is not running in both hosting and xampp  but running on 000webhosting